# Code guidance required for creating mysql table from what is returned by the CFDBINFO Tag

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Working with the following code..

I had tried till now to create the mysql table from the cfdbinfo, i am missing few things things here like:

1. unique key
2. Index key

here is the following try by me, please provide your enhancements

```
<cffunction access="public" name="advancedbackup" returntype="any">
  <cfargument name="structform" default="" required="no" type="struct">
  <cfset var myStruct = "">
  <cfset getInfo = getBackupDatabaseTables('szone')>
  <cfset getTableEngines = valueList(getInfo.name)>
  <cfdbinfo datasource="supportzone" name="getColumns" type="columns" table="#ListLast(arguments.structform.ID,'~')#" />
  <cfsavecontent variable="tableName">
  CREATE TABLE `<cfoutput>#ListLast(arguments.structform.ID,'~')#</cfoutput>`(
  </cfsavecontent>
  <cfsavecontent variable="tableContents">
  <cfloop query="getColumns">
    <CFOUTPUT> `#COLUMN_NAME#` 
      <cfif COLUMN_SIZE GT 255 AND TYPE_NAME NEQ 'varchar'>
        text
        <cfelseif TYPE_NAME IS 'datetime'>
        datetime
        <cfelseif TYPE_NAME IS 'timestamp'>
        timestamp
        <cfelse>
        #TYPE_NAME#(#COLUMN_SIZE#) 
      </cfif>
      <cfif IS_PRIMARYKEY IS 'Yes'>
        AUTO_INCREMENT
      </cfif>
      ,
      <cfif IS_PRIMARYKEY IS 'No'>
        DEFAULT
        <cfif COLUMN_DEFAULT_VALUE IS ''>
          NULL,
          <cfelse>
          '#COLUMN_DEFAULT_VALUE#'
          <cfif IS_NULLABLE IS 'No'>
            NOT NULL,
            <cfelse>
            NULL,
          </cfif>
        </cfif>
      </cfif>
    </CFOUTPUT>
  </cfloop>
  <cfoutput> PRIMARY KEY (`
    <cfif getColumns.IS_PRIMARYKEY IS 'Yes'>
      #getColumns.COLUMN_NAME#
    </cfif>
    `)
    ) ENGINE =
    <cfif ListFindNoCase(getTableEngines,ListLast(arguments.structform.ID,'~'),',') NEQ 0>
      #getInfo.Engine# AUTO_INCREMENT=#getInfo.AUTO_INCREMENT#
    </cfif>
    ; </cfoutput>
  </cfsavecontent>
  <cfset fTable = tableName & tableContents>
  <cfdump var="#ftable#" abort>
```

So basically, getBackupDatabaseTables is getting the following query

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS 
        from szone
```

Comment: Use [SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html)?

Comment: I used the above syntax and tried with the following: `<cfquery name="createTable">
    SHOW CREATE TABLE #ListLast(arguments.structform.ID,'~')#
  </cfquery>
  <cfdump var="#createTable#">
  <cfset lstTable = queryGetRow(createTable,1)>
  <cfdump var="#lstTable#" abort>`. But it throws an Error. **The column name CREATE TABLE is invalid.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to copy the structure of an existing table to a new table. I would create a template table in your db, something like backup_tbl_tmp. It can have all the keys and indexes you need. Then to create a new table (in MySQL which I'm assuming your using...) just do:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name LIKE backup_tbl_tmp;
```

For MSSQL use:

```
SELECT * INTO new_table_name FROM backup_tbl WHERE 0=1;
```

Note that in MSSQL the indexes will not be copied. If you want to copy the data into the new table drop the WHERE clause.

Comment: i am not trying to copy the structure, what @perter above said, i need like that

Comment: Update Here, I solved using the following code provided by @peter. `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytabl`, Then i am using this so the name does not contain spaces and i can actually fetch the query properly. `<cfset QueryAddColumn(createTable, "createNewTable",createTable['CREATE TABLE'])>`

Comment: Now, I am trying to generate the Insert Statements of the mysql table, any idea, how that can be achieved. like this: `insert into tbl(id,name,email) values('1','Peter','peter@qwbmail.com');` and son on till the records in the mysql query